# Pymysql execute() - return value is not equal to the number of affected rows

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm using pymysql to connect to a local MySQL installation. I've made a connection as shown below, but my question is about the return value from the execute() call on the last line.

The [documentation](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html) says the return value of the execute method is equal to the number of rows affected. I know the database table has exactly 205299 rows, so would anyone be able to tell me why I'm seeing the much larger number of 18446744073709551615?

```
>>> import pymysql
>>> conn = pymysql.connect(
...   host='localhost',
...   port=3306,
...   user='username',
...   passwd='password',
...   db='dbname',
...   cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.SSCursor
... )
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT support_id FROM tablename")
18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the problem is in using `SSCursor`. Reading down the documentation you provided you can find what are the [limitations](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.SSCursor):

> There are limitations, though. The MySQL protocol doesn’t support returning the total number of rows, so the only way to tell how many rows there are is to iterate over every row returned. Also, it currently isn’t possible to scroll backwards, as only the current row is held in memory.

So if you want to know how many rows are affected use buffered cursor `conn.cursor()` instead of server one.

Note: affected rows may not be equal to number of rows in table.